# iOS app with MoviePlayer won't show player controls

Tags: ios, swift, movieplayer

I'm trying to create a simple app with two buttons that trigger two videos.

Right now I have coded the first video:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?


    func playVideo01() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video01", ofType: "mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            moviePlayer?.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Fullscreen
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFit
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
    }
```

If I build the app, I cannot stop it: my movie player does not show any controls.

*Can anyone help me?*

Comment: this code is working fine for me

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried this and got control buttons. If I hit "Done" in the top left corner, nothing happens ...